# Obtener el nombre de un objeto en C#

Tags: c#, objeto

¿Puedo obtener el nombre con el que e instanciado un objeto y guardarlo en un string?

```
     float[] objeto1 = new float[4];
     float[] objeto2 = new float[5];
     new Vectores().MejoresAlumnos(objeto1 , objeto2);

     class Vectores
        {               
            public string MejoresAlumnos(float[] notas1, float[] notas2)
                {
                   this.notas1 = notas1;
                   this.notas2 = notas2;
                   return notas1.Length > notas2.Length ? notas1.ToString() : notas2.ToString();
                }
    }
```

Evidentemente con el `.toString()` no es posible hacerlo pero... ¿Hay alguna manera de conseguirlo?

Me gustaría poder recibir el nombre del parámetro que le paso al método `MejoresAlumnos`, es decir, en este ejemplo simple quisiera recibir un `string` con el valor de `objeto2`

Comment: se puede pero es complicar las cosas innecesariamente

Comment: @sstan, si notas2 es mas grande entonces retorna "notas2", eso es lo que yo entendí, pero yo no publiqué la pregunta de arriba

Comment: No entiendo el objetivo. Pareciera que quieres aprovechar un parámetro para enviar dos datos, unos valorres numéricos (`float[]`) y un nombre. Si es así, aparte de complicarte la vida en demasía, no sería la forma apropiada de hacerlo, una clase específica o un [KeyValuePair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) sería más apropiado

Comment: Edito la pregunta principal porque al parecer no esta claro lo que pregunto

Comment: @frikinside No es ningun objetivo, es simplemente saber si es posible hacerlo o no, en cualquier caso revisare las opciones que comentas.

Comment: @sstan, ojo por Reflexion si se pueden sacar los nombres de parámetros o hasta ejecutar comandos, pero otra cosa es lo que pide Edulon, porque un array se pasa por valor por referencia, o sea se crea una copia de la variable pero no se copia el array porque es un objeto, eso si queda por referencia, pero al crear nueva variable no se sabe el nombre de la original desde adentro del método.

Comment: por ejemplo si quieres obtener "notas1" y "notas2" puedes hacer `MethodBase metodo = (typeof (Alumno)).GetMethod("MejoresAlumnos");
            var parametro1 = metodo.GetParameters()[0].Name;
            var parametro2 = metodo.GetParameters()[1].Name;`

Comment: los nombres de parámetros SI se sacan, pero lo que quiere Edulon se conoce como `argumento` que esta donde se llama al metodo, no donde se recibe (que se conoce como parametro). Ahi si, no se...

Comment: @Edulon, usted meta todo en un diccionario y con eso soluciona.

Comment: @derloopkat: me retracto, lo que mencionas sí se puede, me equivoqué. Gracias.

Comment: por lo que veo, tu idea es saber cual de los dos array es mas largo. por lo tanto, si devuelves el nombre del array como string, que harias despues. Supongo que con reflexion se podra. estoy en lo correcto? si es asi podrias editar la pregunta y aclarar eso ahi?

Comment: para mi que quiere hacer un programa tipo instituto con promedios y listas de mejores estudiantes. A ver voy a publicar algo aunque no se si es la idea..... igual despues lo puedo borrar

Comment: @gbianchi creo que está bastante claro lo que pido, conocer el nombre de un objeto, sea cual sea ese objeto, lo que pongo en el mensaje principal es tan solo un ejemplo, no necesito ese código para nada, tan solo quiero saber si puedo obtener el nombre de un objeto. Gracias a todos por la colaboración

Comment: Lo que pedis esta claro, lo que te estoy diciendo es si puedes responder la catarata de comentarios despues de tu edicion, pq si no parece que discutimos entre nosotros sobre tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto retorna el nombre de la variable local dentro del mismo método.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float[] objeto1 = new float[4];
    float[] objeto2 = new float[5];
    Console.WriteLine(GetName(()=>objeto1));
}

static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)expr.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Imprime:

> objeto1

Si tienes C# 6.0 o superior alcanza con

```
Console.Write(nameof(objeto1));
```